# Dtypes and memory

Tags: pandas

Hello I am using pandas read table function and defining all my dtypes to try to improve speed and memory. Using the code below and still getting the following error:

---

> C:\Users\gallachj\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2728:
>   DtypeWarning: Columns (26) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on
>   import or set low_memory=False.   interactivity=interactivity,
>   compiler=compiler, result=result)

Any suggestions on to why this is?

---

`startTime = datetime.now()
start = time.time()`

`from datetime import datetime`

`for i in Index:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(r'''C:\Lifetests''',sns[i]))`

```
if os.path.isfile(sns[i] + '_stitch.txt') and 'Power Meter (W)' and 'Date Time' in open(sns[i] + '.txt').read():` 
    df = pd.read_table(sns[i] + '.txt', sep='\t', header=0, error_bad_lines=False, dtype= {"Sample":"int64", "Date Time":"object","Elapsed Time (hr)":"float64","Power Meter (V)":"float64", "Power Meter (W)":"float64","BRF TEC (V)":"float64","LBO TEC (V)":"float64", "Base Plate Thermistor (ohm)":"float64","Base Plate Temp (C)":"float64","Internal Photodiode (W)":"float64","Internal Photodiode (ADC)":"float64","Current (A)":"float64","Main Temp Drive (V)":"float64","DIO-0 (hex)":"object","DIO-2 (hex)":"object","DIO-4 (hex)":"object","DIO-5 (hex)":"object","Annotation":"object"})`

   `df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time']) 
    Time_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Date Time']) 
    Time_sorted = Time_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset='Date Time', keep='last')  
    Time_sorted.to_csv(sns[i] + '_timestamp_sort.txt', sep='\t')`


elif os.path.isfile(sns[i] + '_stitch.txt') and '(G18.1)' and 'Date Time' in open(sns[i] + '.txt').read(): 
    df = pd.read_table(sns[i] + '.txt', sep='\t', header=0, error_bad_lines=False, dtype= {"Sample (G18.1)":"int64", "Date Time":"object","Elapsed Time (hr)":"float64","Head Hours (hr)":"float64", "FAP Hours (hr)":"float64","Detector Power (W)":"float64","Controller Power (W)":"float64", "Controller Current (A)":"float64","Resonator Temp (degC)":"float64","BRF Temp (degC)":"float64","SHG Temp (degC)":"float64","THG Temp (degC)":"float64","Etalon Temp (degC)":"float64","Heat Sink Temp (degC)":"float64","Resonator Drive (V)":"float64","BRF Drive (V)":"float64","SHG Drive (V)":"float64","THG Drive (V)":"float64","Etalon Drive (V)":"float64", "Legacy Fault (hex)":"object","Head Fault (hex)":"object","Head Fault Latch (hex)":"object", "A Temp Sense (adc)":"float64","B Temp Sense (adc)":"float64","C Temp Sense (adc)":"float64","D Temp Sense (adc)":"float64","Resonator Temp Sense (adc)":"float64", "Heat Sink Temp Sense (adc)":"float64","Photodiode (adc)":"float64","Microcontroller Temp Sense (adc)":"float64", "Head DAC1 Output (dac)":"float64","Head DAC2 Output (dac)":"float64",\
                       "A Heater PWM (%)":"float64","B Heater PWM (%)":"float64", "C Heater PWM (%)":"float64","D Heater PWM (%)":"float64","Head GPIOA (hex)":"object","Head GPIOB (hex)":"object", "Head GPIOC (hex)":"object","Head GPIOD (hex)":"object","Annotation":"object"})#, dtype ={'Date Time': np.dtype('M')})
    df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])
    Time_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Date Time'])
    Time_sorted = Time_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset='Date Time', keep='last')   
    Time_sorted.to_csv(sns[i] + '_timestamp_sort.txt', sep='\t')


elif os.path.isfile(sns[i] + '_stitch.txt') and '(mW)' and 'Date Time' in open(sns[i] + '.txt').read():    
    df = pd.read_table(sns[i] + '.txt', sep='\t', header=0, error_bad_lines=False, dtype= {"Sample":"int64","Date Time":"object","Elapsed Time (hr)":"float64","Power (V)":"float64","Power (mW)":"float64","Current (A)":"float64","Main Temp (degC)":"float64","BRF Temp (degC)":"float64","SHG Temp (degC)":"float64","THG Temp (degC)":"float64","Main Temp Drive (volt)":"float64","Alt PD (adc)":"float64","UV PD (adc)":"float64","IR PD (adc)":"float64","DIO0 (hex)":"object","DIO2 (hex)":"object","DIO4 (hex)":"object","DIO5 (hex)":"object","Annotation":"object"})#, dtype ={'Date Time': np.dtype('M')})
    df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])
    Time_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Date Time'])
    Time_sorted = Time_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset='Date Time', keep='last')   
    Time_sorted.to_csv(sns[i] + '_timestamp_sort.txt', sep='\t')

else:
    print("{} does not exist ".format(sns[i] + '.txt'))
```

`print(datetime.now() - startTime)
print('It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds.')`